# Power Query identify parent records in hierarchical nested loops

Tags: excel, powerquery

The data is a series of nested hierarchies.  Within the loops are child records. The data is a list of components and sub components. The subcomponents may have subcomponents themselves.

The top of the loops are parent records to these nested child records. These loops can be nested within each other.

The data set is ordered so the records in proper order.

Below is screenshot of how it appears as an indented hierarchical text file.

Basically need to identify the top level of of each loop so I can get other column information from them to compare to nested child values. Nested child properties should be same as parent. I need to check this is the case.

I have no code to show. Not sure how to proceed. Group By seems promising, but need to figure out way to recurse back up hierarchy to the top of current loop, and relate that to each of its child records, so I can compare their properties.

[image]

Sample data, first column Index is simply line number, and second column Level Number is the hierarchy level.

There is unique combination of line number and hierarchy level that would identify each level's parent "Index-Level". I would like to associate this Parent Index-Level with each of its child levels.

The data is text format but is brought into Power Query where the analysis has to happen.

```
Index   Level Number  Parent Index-Level
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
11  11
12  12
13  13
14  14
15  14
16  14
17  14
18  14
19  14
20  14
21  13
22  13
23  13
24  14
25  14
26  14
27  11
28  9
29  9
30  9
31  9
32  9
33  9
34  9
35  8
36  9
37  10
38  11
39  11
40  12
41  12
42  13
43  13
44  13
45  11
46  12
47  13
48  14
49  14
50  14
```

Comment: Can you show a data sample?

Comment: The relevant data is basically just row/line  number and hierarchy level as depicted by screenshot above. I could add 3rd column to show component name. Parent component could be "car". It's subcomponents could be " engine". Engine subcomponents could be carburetor which could have its own subcomponents etc.

Comment: After engine's subcomponents chain is exhausted, could go to next component such as transmission, them to interior, etc. All the way down to smallest subcomponents. All traceable back up to through nested hierarchy to car. I want to check all subcomponents' properties against its  parent's property

Comment: Again, can you show a data sample? The devil is in the detail. What is the data source? Excel? CSV? Database?

Comment: I havent got time for a full answer today, but I'm imagining a self-Merge (to  the same Query) would be the starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cd6cb346-b30f-4cc2-b088-4ef687833249/power-query-loop-through-hierarchy-of-components-subcomponents?forum=powerquery#4f6bd58a-2465-4c8a-a251-0086af970e1c)  on Microsoft TechNet forum which does what I was looking for though it does run very slowly. For 30k records took more than 30 minutes to complete on i7 cpu, 16 GB RAM, 64bit Excel/Power Query machine. This is Power Query limitation.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle3"]}[Content],
    ParentIndex = Table.AddColumn(Source, "ParentIndex", each let Index=[Index], LN=[Level Number] in List.Max(Table.SelectRows(Source, each _[Index] < Index and _[Level Number]=LN-1)[Index])),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(ParentIndex,{"ParentIndex"},ParentIndex,{"Index"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "NewColumn", {"Level Number"}, {"Level Number.1"})
in
    #"Expanded NewColumn"
```

In case others are interested in other solutions to get past this performance limitation I am [exploring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674269/excel-vba-ado-sql-syntax-error-in-from-clause) VBA/ADO SQL solution but haven't quite got there yet.

Also looking at using Python xlWings as [potential solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672315/python-get-parent-index-from-child-index-child-level-and-parent-level) too.