# Python - get parent index from child index, child level and parent level

Tags: python-2.7

I need help to figure out how to get parent index from child index, child-level and parent-level using Python.

I have dataset with three columns: index, child-level and parent-level.

The records are in order of hierarchy.

Index is just the line number of record.

Child-level is number indicating level in hierarchy of nested parent child records.

Parent-level = child-level - 1

My challenge is, for each record, I want to use Python to get each record's parent index.

I suspect a list comprehension might be used to get the max index value where the self join index < child.index and the self join level = child.level

This is a visual representation of the data set.

[image]

This is sample data and expected result. Goal is to get parent index.

```
Index, Child-Level,Parent-Level,Parent-Index
1,1,1,1
2,2,1,1
4,4,3,3
9,9,8,8
3,3,2,2
5,5,4,4
8,8,7,7
6,6,5,5
7,7,6,6
10,10,9,9
11,11,10,10
12,12,11,11
13,13,12,12
14,14,13,13
15,14,13,13
16,14,13,13
17,14,13,13
18,14,13,13
19,14,13,13
20,14,13,13
21,13,12,12
22,13,12,12
23,13,12,12
24,14,13,23
25,14,13,23
26,14,13,23
27,11,10,10
28,9,8,8
29,9,8,8
30,9,8,8
31,9,8,8
32,9,8,8
33,9,8,8
34,9,8,8
35,8,7,7
36,9,8,35
37,10,9,36
38,11,10,37
39,11,10,37
40,12,11,39
41,12,11,39
42,13,12,41
43,13,12,41
44,13,12,41
45,11,10,37
46,12,11,45
47,13,12,46
48,14,13,47
49,14,13,47
50,14,13,47
51,14,13,47
52,14,13,47
53,14,13,47
54,14,13,47
55,13,12,46
56,13,12,46
57,13,12,46
58,9,8,35
59,9,8,35
60,9,8,35
61,9,8,35
62,8,7,7
63,8,7,7
64,8,7,7
65,8,7,7
66,8,7,7
67,8,7,7
68,8,7,7
```

Comment: This is all great, but what's your question?

Comment: Thanks. Question was vaguely worded in title, but was not clear. Have clarified question in question body.

Comment: I edited the title to hopefully better reflect what you are asking. One way to approach this is to use a node library like networkx to graph your tree, and then traverse it. You can also implement any of the tree traversal algorithms. What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: I changed title back. Your edit suggests a potential solution. Rather than do that in title, can you offer an answer perhaps?  I have dataset with three columns: index, child-level and parent-level. I want to get parent-index. I have a TSQL solution for this in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639349/sql-query-get-parent-index-from-level-and-child-index)