# Excel VBA ADO SQL - Syntax error in From clause

Tags: sql, vba, ado

The following SQL in VBA ADO gives the 'syntax error in From clause' error.

```
Sub RunSQL2()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strCon As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strRangeAddress As String
    Dim dataRange As Range

    strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
        & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cn.Open strCon

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mydata")
    strRangeAddress = ActiveSheet.Name & "$" & ws.Range("A1:C30020").Address(False, False)

        strSQL = strSQL & " (select s.* from "
strSQL = strSQL & " (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by child_level order by child_index,child_level) [rownum] from [" & strRangeAddress & "] t) s "
strSQL = strSQL & " where [rownum] = 1) u "
strSQL = strSQL & " join (select t2.*, 1 as  [rownum] from [" & strRangeAddress & "] t2) v "
strSQL = strSQL & " on (v.parent_level = u.child_level and v.[rownum] = u.[rownum]) "
strSQL = strSQL & " union select  w.child_index,w.child_level,w.child_level,w.child_index "
strSQL = strSQL & " from [" & strRangeAddress & "] w "
strSQL = strSQL & " where w.child_index = 1 "
strSQL = strSQL & " order by v.child_index;"


    rs.Open strSQL, cn

    Debug.Print rs.GetString

End Sub
```

The debug.print of strSQL is:

```
select v.child_index,v.child_level,v.parent_level,u.child_index as  parent_index 
from  
  (select s.* 
   from  
     (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by child_level order by child_index,child_level) [rownum] 
      from [mydata$A1:C30020] t
     ) s  
   where [rownum] = 1
  ) u  
join 
  (select t2.*, 1 as  [rownum] 
   from [mydata$A1:C30020] t2
  ) v  on (v.parent_level = u.child_level and v.[rownum] = u.[rownum])  

union 

select  w.child_index,w.child_level,w.child_level,w.child_index  
from [mydata$A1:C30020] w  
where w.child_index = 1  
order by v.child_index;
```

When I use simple strSQL string the connection works and returns results. This works:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & strRangeAddress & "]"
```

I think I have correct syntax. Is it possible the error arises from non compatible SQL?  For example can ADO do 'Partition by'?

I am using Excel 2010 64 bit Office.

Comment: I have reformated your long inline SQL query because it was not understandable at all. When the review get accepted, check the query again to ensure this is correct. I'll have a better look to your issue later

Comment: **Pro tip**: when you build such long and complicated query in your code using `strSQL = strSQL &` , add a  `& vbcrlf` at the end of each line so the query becomes understandable when you `debug.print strSQL`

Comment: The Jet/ACE SQL engine which you use to connect to an Excel workbook does not support window functions in its dialect, so you cannot use `RowNumber()`, `Over()`, or `Partition`.

Comment: In addition to the problem mentioned by @Parfait the query would never work as a `UNION` requires that you have the same amount of  columns in the first part and the second part. Your query selects 5 columns before the `UNION` and merely 4 columns after the `UNION`.

Comment: thanks Thomas looks great. I do use line breaks but at this stage I like to minimize complexity.

Comment: Ralph query does return desired results in 4 columns on SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a correlated count aggregate query for row number in place of the window function as this subquery should by compliant in Jet/ACE SQL:

```sql
SELECT v.child_index, v.child_level, v.parent_level, u.child_index, v.parent_index 
FROM
  (SELECT s.* 
   FROM  
     (SELECT t.*, (SELECT count(*) FROM [mydata$A1:C30020] sub 
                   WHERE sub.child_index <= t.child_index
                   AND sub.child_level = t.child_level) as [rownum] 
      FROM [mydata$A1:C30020] t
     ) s  
   WHERE [rownum] = 1
  ) u  
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT t2.*, 1 as [rownum] 
   FROM [mydata$A1:C30020] t2
  ) v  
ON (v.parent_level = u.child_level) AND (v.[rownum] = u.[rownum])  

UNION 

SELECT w.child_index, w.child_level, w.parent_level, w.child_index, w.parent_index 
FROM [mydata$A1:C30020] w  
WHERE w.child_index = 1  
ORDER BY v.child_index;
```

Comment: I deleted the question you answered after realizing same. Just tried the SQL in VBA and it gives 'No value given for one or more required parameters' error. I am not on machine that has SQL Server or Access so can't test SQL outside of VBA.

Comment: Can you verify if top header of `[mydata$A1:C30020]` has fields columns exactly as specified: child_index, child_level, parent_level, child_index, parent_index.

Comment: correction child_index, child_level, parent_level, child_index as parent_index